# How to perform string find and replace on Tensorflow String Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I currently am using the Tensorflow dataset api to perform some augmentations to images at a specified path. The filename itself contains information that states whether to augment the file or not. So what I want to do is read in the files from the dataset and for each file, perform a find within the filename and if I find a specific substring, then set a bool flag and replace the substring with "".

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'find'

I can't perform a "find" on the tensor with dtype string entries because find is not a part of the Tensor, so I am trying to figure out how I can go about performing the above action. I have shared some code below that I think demonstrates what I am trying to do.  Performance is important, so I would prefer to do this the correct way if anyone sees that I am going about doing this via the Dataset API incorrectly.

```py
def preproc_img(filenames):
  def parse_fn(filename):
    augment_inst = False
    if cfg.SPLIT_INTO_INST:
      #*****************************************************
      #*** THIS IS WHERE THE LOGIC IS CURRENTLY BREAKING ***
      #*****************************************************
      if filename.find('_data_augmentation') != -1:
        augment_inst = True
        filename = filename.replace('_data_augmentation', '')

    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    img = tf.image.decode_image(image_string, channels=3)
    return dict(zip([filename], [img]))   

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
  dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  return iterator.get_next()


def perform_train():
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    filenames = helper.get_image_paths()
    next_batch = preproc_img(filenames)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    with sess .graph.as_default():
      sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

      dat = sess.run(next_batch)
      # I would now go about calling any of my tf op code below
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`tf.regex_replace`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/regex_replace) for replacing text in a `tf.string` tensor.

```
filename = tf.regex_replace(filename, "_data_augmentation", "")
```

For TF 2.0

```
filename = tf.strings.regex_replace(filename, "_data_augmentation", "")
```

Comment: Is there a way of detecting if the substring is in the filename?  Reason I ask is because I use this to determine whether to set a flag or not for augmentation processing.  Also do you by chance know what version of TF this was added?  I am running 1.5 and I get the message 

"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'regex_replace'"

Comment: Ok so it seems regex_replace is available from 1.7 and newer should anyone else need to use it as well.  Thanks nessuno!

Comment: You're welcome! However, if you want to check if the filename contains the string, you can do something like: `contains = tf.equal(tf.size(tf.string_split([filename],"")), tf.size(tf.string_split([tf.regex_replace(filename, "/_data_augmentation/", "")])))`

This computes and compare the length of the string before and after the application of `tf.regex_replace`.

Also, if I solved your problem, please remember to mark the answer as accpeted!ì

Comment: Truly helpful!!  Marked as correct answer and again thank you!  Been trying to figure this out since yesterday :)

Comment: I tried making a slight edit to the answer but because it wasn't 6 characters or more it wouldn't allow me to submit.

The regex expression in TF wasn't working correctly with the forward slashes at the start and end but worked fine without them. So the above regex expression should be "_data_augmentation" instead for anyone that comes across this in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to edit the answer with your suggestion

Comment: Please, note that the API has changed for TF 2.0. Now, it's `tf.strings.regex_replace`.

Comment: if anyone wants to check if a given string matches the regex pattern, you may use [`tf.strings.regex_full_match`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_full_match)